# CSS Keyframes animation go back to initial state

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm calling an animation like this:

```
document.getElementById('banner').className = "changeColorToIndigo";
```

Then I've got the CSS property:

```
div.changeColorToIndigo {
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: changeColorToIndigo;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

And the keyframes animation:

```
@keyframes changeColorToIndigo {
from {background-color: #00BBD2;}
to {background-color: #3F51B5;}
}
```

But the animation goes back to it's initial state after the animation has completed, why is that? I've set the fill mode to forwards and specified the `to` (100%) property.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put your code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9e01e0y/), and it works fine for me

HTML

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #00BBD2;
}

div.changeColorToIndigo {
    animation-name: changeColorToIndigo;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeColorToIndigo {
    from {background-color: #00BBD2;}
    to {background-color: #3F51B5;}
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner').addClass('changeColorToIndigo');
})
```

Comment: I found the culprit. I had a event listener that removed the class once finished, as I wanted to have it "clean". So, if I remove the class, it'll revert to it's initial state?